# AWS S3 ObjectCreated triggers lambda with delay (Lambda Cold-start)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I've configured the simple trigger for **lambda**, which process image up on arrive to **S3**.
In general, the **lambda** triggered with minimum delay, many times in the same second when **S3** received the image.
But, occasionally, around 7% cases, there is a delay between *image received* and *ObjectCreated* event, this delay could be up to **19 seconds!!** (9-10 seconds in average).

Any idea how to avoid this delay?

This delay makes me impossible to use **S3->Lambda** triggers for high performance real time apps.

Answer (score 5):

After a while, trying to investigate and googling.

In parallel asking AWS support about the case, I finally got the answer from AWS:

--

> .. Lambda invoked the function pretty much immediately after we received
>   the event, but the specific request id you shared was for an invoke
>   that had to **coldstart**, which added nearly **10 seconds** of extra latency.
>
> The function is in the **VPC**, where cold starts tend to take a **few
>   seconds longer**. **Coldstarts** cannot be eliminated but for high volume
>   functions the incidence of cold start should be lower once you scale
>   up and more **containers** are available for reuse.

As you may see from the answer, if you are trying to make a high performance / high traffic real time app, S3->Lambda will not fit in your requirements.

My next question would be, if I trigger the lambda directly from the script that uploads the image, will it help?
Or I should avoid of using lambda at all on this kind of applications and leave it only for background data processing?

Hope this answer will help someone else..

Comment: Calling lambda directly from your script will not prevent the coldstart. The bigger your code, the longer the coldstart, so if you can't reduce the size of your script / executable, the longer the coldstart.
Some anecdotal evidence found in blog posts around seems to suggest that Coldstart are unlikely to happen if you have a lambda call within a few minutes of the last one, so if you want to avoid then, perhaps have a timed event being produced that would trigger the lambda every few minutes?

Answer (score 1):

After 28th of November 2019, cold starts for Lambdas that are inside VPC are no longer causing that much delays, due to AWS Lambda service improvements. You can find out more about it here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/

There are a lot of other ways to reduce cold starts in Lambda, but it mostly depends on the use case. The most common is to reduce code size of Lambda or use other runtime, Node or Python for example.

Comment: you said "no longer causing much delay", which means it still causing delay?
I completely moved out from lambda since my last post, and switched fully to kubernetes.
But would like to know updates, what are the practical numbers for the delay currently?

Comment: You would need to create a proper test to get exact numbers, but from the article that I've linked I see, that the delay is around 500 ms, because there is always some cold start, no matter if you are using VPC or not. Still in general I do not recommend to use architectures, where you choose VPC because it's annoying and complicates a lot of stuff. If it's possible, simply avoid using VPC, it just ruins the simplicity of Serverless approach. In case of triggering lambda when S3 object is created, there is no need to use VPC.